# Effect of transition energy gap and frequency of microwave on appearance of CW EPR spectrum

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, epr-spectroscopy

Consider continuous-wave EPR for species with only one unpaired electron in the following argument.

The interaction energy in the presence of external magnetic field of strength *B* is given by

$$E = Bg\mathrm{m_s}\mu_\mathrm{B} - Bg_{\mathrm{N}}\mathrm{m_I}\mu_\mathrm{N} + a\mathrm{m_sm_I}$$

Taking the specific selection rules for EPR transition into account,

$$\Delta E = Bg\mu_\mathrm{B} + a\mathrm{m_I}$$

1. Just to check my understanding.

The figure below illustrates splitting of states in the presence of magnetic field, when the only unpaired electron is coupled to a spin-half nucleus$^{[1]}$ :

[image]

assuming $a$ and nuclear $g$ to be positive and isotropic.

Using the last equation above,

EPR I: $\Delta E = Bg\mu_\mathrm{B} -\frac{1}{2}a$

EPR II: $\Delta E = Bg\mu_\mathrm{B} +\frac{1}{2}a$

So EPR II transition energy gap is bigger. Then shouldn't the EPR II signal appears at lower field in the EPR spectrum? Logically, if the energy gap is already big, to make the gap coincides with the frequency of incident microwaves, the external magnetic field only need to be increased relatively little. But the opposite is shown in the EPR spectrum inserted. Did I understand the concept wrongly?

2. This second figure encountered in the same reference book$^{[2]}$ baffles me:

[image]

The figure shows that, when the frequency of incident microwaves is increased, the separation between two lines in a multiplet also increases. Doesn't that imply the hyperfine splitting constant will also change? But I read hyperfine interaction is field-independent.$^{[2]}$

---

Chechik V, Carter E, Murphy D. Electron Paramagnetic Resonance. Oxford: OUP Oxford; 2016.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYWzA.png) page 12

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8R2z8.png) page 36